# Can a character with the Torch Fighter feat still treat a torch as an improvised weapon to benefit from class features or other feats?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, improvised-weaponry

The [Torch Fighter](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/torch-bearer-combat/) feat allows a character to treat a torch as a light mace with 1 extra fire damage and allows the use of any feat or class feature that would apply to a light mace when wielding a torch.

But is it still treated as an improvised weapon for class features or feats that specifically apply to these (such as the [Breaker](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian/archetypes/paizo-barbarian-archetypes/breaker/)'s Battle Scavenger feature) ?

Answer (score 2):

Torch Fighter says:

> You treat a torch as a light weapon that deals bludgeoning damage equal to that of a light mace of its size plus 1 point of fire damage, and you do not incur penalties as you would for using it as an improvised weapon.

The feat doesn't say that you *may* treat a torch as a light weapon, but that you *do* do so. Thus, *for this character*, a torch is no longer an improvised weapon.

RAW, then, would indicate that you can't still treat it as an improvised weapon for other purposes.

This GM would see no problem in letting it slide *with this feat/feature combination*, though: the feat amounts to a weak version of [Weapon Specialization](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/weapon-specialization-combat-final/) (one point of extra damage instead of two, even if it is fire), albeit one which is rather easier to get. It's also a fairly weak weapon for a typical barbarian to use (1d6/x2 vs, say, a 1d8/x3 Warhammer or 1d6, 18-20/x2 Scimitar, just sticking with one-handed weapons).

Comment: Actually, I see another problem with this feat : a torch cannot be enhanced as a weapon and inevitably becomes a weaker option at higher levels.

Comment: I think there's a way around that with http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/master-craftsman-final/ - since the Breaker treats torches as weapons, they'd be able to craft a masterwork torch and enchant it themselves.